# How do I use regex for an integer range from 18-99?

Tags: javascript, regex, integer, range

I'm trying to create a javascript regex for a Google Form to validate an answer for an age related question.  I want the user to only be able to enter whole number values between 18 and 99.

These values must be numerical only, cannot lead with zero(s), be negative, or include decimals. They must be whole positive numbers only.

I'm very new to regex this is my best attempt.

```
(1[89]|[2-9][0-9])

\d(1[89]|[2-9][0-9])
```

The first attempt will keep answers within my range (18 to 99) however it allows values with decimals, preceding zeros, and even trailing letters.

[image: regEx1]

Second attempt when I use \d It only seems to accept values that lead with a zero despite if they include a decimal or trailing letter.

[image: regEx2]

Comment: hello try this :
https://regex101.com/r/axTLup/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you can make a capture group like this ;

```
^(1[89]|[2-9][0-9])$
```

https://regex101.com/r/m2icLR/1

Comment: I knew I was overlooking something simple. This works exactly as I need.  So grateful for this place, thank you!

Comment: you are welcome! don't hesitate if you need something else !  Please mark as answered !

Answer (score 0):

You can Try ^.{18,99}$

Explanation:

. dot stands for all characters. Except \n for which you will have to use s DOTALL flag.